# C# loading picturebox - Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

```
    private void Button_Generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        Download_xl();
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;

    }

   public void Download_xl()
    {

        string strPath = Application.StartupPath;
        SqlTable sqltbl = new SqlTable();

        saleno = comboBox2.Text;

        FindBaseGradeStaple();
        FindLoanID();

        qry = "Select * from dbname.dbo.vw_SingleSales where saleno = '" +
                saleno + "'";

        if (rs.State == 1) { rs.Close(); }
        rs.Open(qry, sqltbl.GetSqlConnection());

        if (rs.RecordCount > 0)
        {
            Excel.Application xlapp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook wkb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(strPath + @"\Sales_Contract.xlsx");
            Excel.Worksheet wksht = wkb.Sheets["BaleValue"];
            xlapp.Visible = false;

            wksht.Range["A9"].CopyFromRecordset(rs);


            saleno = saleno.Replace(@"/", "-");
            savepath = Application.StartupPath;
            wkb.SaveAs(savepath + @"\Single Sales - " + saleno + ".xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault);
            xlapp.Visible = true;
            }
        else
        {

            MessageBox.Show("No Records for the Saleno - " + saleno);
        }

    }
```

rs in the above piece of code is ADODB.Recordset.

In the above piece of code the pictureBox1 doesn't display immediately after clicking the button. Instead it takes a while until some tasks of Download_xl have been executed. I want to show the picture and run the Download_xl function simultaneously. The above code is in C#. I took a look at multithreading but since I'm relatively new to c# I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: is `Download_xl()` awaitable?

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: There is a confusing in your code. You said ``doesn't display immediately``, but initially, ``pictureBox1.Visible = true;``. Your picture is shown right away ?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - You can try to force display by calling `pictureBox1.Refresh();`

Comment: @TaW `pictureBox1.Refresh();` after the `pictureBox1.Visible = true;` would work, but the UI would still be blocked whilst `Download_xl()` is executing

Comment: Not knowing much about `Download_xl()` this is just speculation.

Comment: @p3tch You are right. picturebox1.refresh() indeed shows the loading picture but it doesn't animate. Its a gif. How do I make Download_xl() awaitable..? This function creates an excel file and fills it with records from an sql recordset.

Comment: A Gif animation will only run if the pbox has focus and the ui thread isn't busy. Try `pictureBox1.Focus();` . But you may have to move the download away from the UI thread..

Comment: Need to see `FindBaseGradeStaple()` and `FindLoanID()`.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem @KarthikeyanNatarajan ?

Comment: @p3tch Yes I did. I used Background_Workers. I displayed the pictureBox1 before calling a Background worker to do the job of running Download_XL (Do_Work) and then in the Runworkercompleted I wrapped up by hiding the picturebox1. That resolved the whole thing. Thanks for asking though.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code doesn't work because the UI thread is blocked by `Download_xl()`. Using `pictureBox1.Refresh()` works because it forces that UI element to update before the blocking code starts. Your .GIF the picture box is containing doesn't animate because the UI thread is still blocked by `Download_xl()`.

You can make your event handler `async void`. Within in, you can asynchronously await a Task that runs `Download_xl()`. Doing so will not block your UI whilst whatever long-running process is being executed, but your image will not become invisible until after `Download_xl()` has finished executing because you're **awaiting** the Task that's executing it with the `await` keyword.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming for more

```
private async void Button_Generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Visible = true;

    await Task.Run(() => Download_xl());

    pictureBox1.Visible = false;
}
```

Obviously you'll need to take care of any multi-threading issues that `Download_xl()` may cause by yourself. Without seeing the code for that method no one can really help you.

If you use my example and make your event handler `async void` then you may want to control how often it can be pressed. Unlike your original code, this will not block the UI thread so the user is able to click multiple times, and each click will start a new Task that executes `Download_xl()`. You could solve this by something as simple as disabling the button at the start of the event and re-enabling it at the end, or have a look into semaphores.

---

Regarding your comment, I can't see what you're doing to `comboBox1` as you've not provided the code, but you'll need to do something like

```
comboBox1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    comboBox1.WhateverMethodYoureAlreadyExecuting();
}));
```

You need to Invoke because `Download_xl()` is now running on another thread (because we're executing it in a Task). Using Invoke will perform whatever action for that UI element on the UI thread and your cross-threading exception should go away.

P.S. `Download_xl()` doesn't follow C# naming conventions, it should be `DownloadXl()` (though that's still not very descriptive)

Comment: Thank you for the response. The code is in Winforms C#. And I did try your suggestion. But the moment I click on the generate button, I get the following error ":System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'comboBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on" This points to the Download_XL() function.

Comment: I need to see `Download_xl()`. From what you've mentioned, you will need to Invoke anything that's on the UI that `Download_xl()` touches @KarthikeyanNatarajan

Comment: Okay I saw you updated your question, but `Download_xl` doesn't have any mention of `comboBox1`. Do `FindBaseGradeStaple()` or `FindLoanID()` reference it? @KarthikeyanNatarajan